# What is the default bibliography package and backend in LaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, biber

According to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib), `biblatex` and `natbib` are packages while `biber` and `bibtex` are backends. If I don't specify either any package or any backend, it still compiles fine. Which package and backend combination is being used in this case?

**demo.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{pub}

\end{document}
```

**pub.bib**

```
@article{janssen1996evaluation,
    title={Evaluation of the DNA fingerprinting method AFLP as a new tool in bacterial taxonomy},
    author={Janssen, Paul and Coopman, Renata and Huys, Geert and Swings, Jean and Bleeker, Marjo and Vos, Pieter and Zabeau, Marc and Kersters, Karel},
    journal={Microbiology},
    volume={142},
    number={7},
    pages={1881--1893},
    year={1996},
    publisher={Soc General Microbiol}
}

@article{vos1995aflp,
    title={AFLP: a new technique for DNA fingerprinting},
    author={Vos, Pieter and Hogers, Rene and Bleeker, Marjo and Reijans, Martin and Van de Lee, Theo and Hornes, Miranda and Friters, Adrie and Pot, Jerina and Paleman, Johan and Kuiper, Martin and others},
    journal={Nucleic acids research},
    volume={23},
    number={21},
    pages={4407--4414},
    year={1995},
    publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}
```

Comment: There is no backend predefined, as LaTeX by itself does not launch any backend. But many *editors* are configured to launch  a backend. Also, `biber` requires `biblatex` to work (albeut `biblatex`can use `bibtex` as a backend). Typically, the code you posted will work with `bibtex`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not really any sense in which there is a 'default' bibliography package for LaTeX. In order to compile your sample document you have used both a TeX engine (most likely `pdflatex`) and `bibtex`, since the `IEEEtr.bst` file that is used when you add `\bibliography{IEEEtr}` requires `bibtex`.

This only appears to be a 'default' because your editor is probably set up so that `bibtex` is the default program for bibliographies.

Had your editor been set to use `biber` as the default program, your document would have failed.

As you can see from your sample document, a specific bibliography package (such as `natbib`) is not strictly needed when using `bibtex` as the backend. However `natbib`+`bibtex` provides good support for Author/Year type citations, which is why many people use it. (`biblatex`+`biber` also provides good Author/Year support along with many other citation styles.)   As discussed in the question you link to, `natbib` and `biblatex` are of course incompatible with each other.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It seems quite common for people to try using `natbib` and `biblatex`, so I think redundancy is safest ;).

Comment: I implicitly assumed that to use `bibtex` backend, I must use either `natbib` or `biblatex` package. This follows from the fact that I don't understand what functionality a backend provides vs. what functionality a package provides very clearly.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock You *must* use `bibtex` with `natbib`. You *should* ideally use `biber` with `biblatex` and not `bibtex`. The two programs are not really comparable: `bibtex` does both sorting and formatting, while `biber` is really only responsible for sorting (and very sophisticated sorting in fact); `biblatex` does all the formatting.