# Collaborating with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, best-practices, collaboration

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361649/25142) says that my TeX editor (TeXstudio) is choosing a bibliography tool for me. But it seems that I have to make the biblatex backend match this bibliography tool in source code for my document to compile.

Thus, if I set the default bib tool to bibtex, I *must* write:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

while if I set the default bib tool to biber, I have to set the backend to `biber` (or leave it out, since `biber` is the default). Mismatching the biblatex setting and the default tool in the editor (e.g., by telling the editor to use bibtex but writing `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}` results in errors like:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "main"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

This is annoying for my own documents when I have to switch my editor's backend. But it's much worse when I'm working with other people. When I change the *source code* to use biblatex, this implies that my co-authors have to figure out how to make their editor use the same bib tool as me, which might not be their preferred method. This isn't a problem if I *don't* use biblatex, because nothing in the source code forces someone to use a particular bib tool. Is it really this difficult, or is there an easier way? It doesn't seem right that changing the source code can break someone else's build system.

Comment: Most editors support magic comments in the source to tell you how to compile. See [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101) for details.  Working collaboratively with `biblatex/biber` can be tricky sometimes, since the versions of the two have to match. It helps a lot for collaborating users to be using the same year of TeX distribution.

Comment: @AlanMunn The comment commands are useful, but only if coauthors are using one of those editors. In particular, emacs is popular, but apparently doesn't support those commands. Distressing to hear that our versions may have to match, too... Is there something in the source code that would make the version matter?

Comment: `emacs+auctex` can usually tell by itself. [get emacs to automatically use biber instead of bibtex](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/129217).  Alternatively, people can compile using `latexmk` which also can tell by itself.  `arara` is another possibility.

Comment: On version matching, there is no backwards compatibility mode that you can specify within the source to match `biber` and `biblatex` versions. See p.7 of the `biblatex` documentation for the range of possibilities.  So there's really no good way around that problem. I have multiple years of TeX Live installed on my machine, so I can adapt to collaborators when needed, and switching (on Mac) is quite trivial.

Comment: In the LaTeX world it is not that outlandish that code changes could "break" the build environment. Load `fontspec` and you must compile your document with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Load and use `pstricks` and you need LaTeX (*not* pdfLaTeX in PDF mode) or XeLaTeX. Load an index package and you need to run an additional indexing tool... Use `\label`s or add a ToC and you need to compile your document at least twice to make sure all references are OK.

Comment: If the collaborative work is supposed to appear in a journal, `biblatex` might not be the best choice. Most journals with LaTeX templates either want manual `thebibliography`s or provide a BibTeX style. Due to the build setup involved for `biblatex` I doubt a lot will accept `biblatex`, but maybe that is slowly changing. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I've now answered this in the comments, I might as well add an actual answer.  There are two main issues with respect to collaborating with people using `biblatex`: build process and version matching.

### Controlling the build process on a per-document basis

The first, as you note, is dealing with people's different default build setups. In this case, what's needed is a way to control compilation on a per-document basis. Many editors support "magic comments" which do exactly this. To control the bibliography processing you can use:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
```

or

```
% !BIB program = biber
```

See the following question for a complete list of possibilities, as well as which editors support them.

- [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/2693)

If you are using `emacs`, `auctex` usually knows which bib program to use. See this question:

- [get emacs to automatically use biber instead of bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129217/2693)

and also:

- [How can I automatically add some local variables info to a C-x C-f new (.tex) file?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/)

Alternatively, you can use `latexmk` to compile the document. `latexmk` is smart enough to tell whether to use `biber` or `bibtex`, and does all of the relevant compiles needed to resolve references and produce the bibliography.

A third option is to use `arara` for compilation. Then you can put the build process directly into the document and tell your collaborators to use `arara` to compile. Most editors can be set up to use it. (There are various questions on the site about setting up different editors to use it.)

### Matching `biber` and `biblatex` versions

A second more serious problem that using `biblatex` poses for collaboration is the fact that versions of `biber` and `biblatex` are very closely connected, and since both are still being developed, there have been many versions over the years.  I should also note here that using the `[backend=bibtex]` package option is really not a viable option for most current `biblatex` styles.

Below is a list from the current  `biblatex` manual.  There is no backwards compatibility modes in either `biber` or `biblatex` which means you really do need to keep versions up-to-date and matching. Ideally then, this means that all collaborators have the same year of TeX Live (or the MikTeX equivalent of it) installed. The most likely problems will arise with Linux users, since Linux packaged distributions often lag behind the current year.

This problem may not be quite as serious as it looks, at least if everyone is using a fairly up-to-date version, and people don't try to compile using the `.bcf` file generated by a different version. This problem can arise, for example, if people are sharing a document in a Dropbox folder, rather than e.g. compiling a local version and managing the collaboration via Git.

Many of us have multiple years of TeX Live installed on our machines. Depending on the OS it's usually not too difficult to switch between them. So this can also be an option.

[image]

Comment: The version compatibility problem only arises if you share compilation artifacts, which is probably bad for other reasons as well. I usually use git and put all artifact file types (*.aux, *.bcf, etc) in my .gitignore, which solves this problem.

Comment: @crockeea Yes, that's what I tried to say in my discussion.  Although if you have someone with a seriously outdated distribution and are tweaking `biblatex` code in the document or using fancy `biber` functions you may encounter real incompatibilities.